# How to use 'Google Places API Web Service' in China?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know The Google Maps APIs are served within China from the domain maps.google.cn

But when I use the 'Places' library, I called textSearch() function via PlacesService. It seems like make a request from 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/' instead of ‘http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/place/’.

The request failed so that I can't search anything out.

Is there anyone can help me to resolve this problem？

Thanks a lot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe somebody has already reported this issue in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765944. Unfortunately, there is no answer in this bug. Feel free to add your comment to the bug.